# pyodbc returns random date instead of None

Tags: python, python-2.7, date, pyodbc

Using pyodbc-3.0.10 under 64-bit Anaconda Python 2.7.12.

I have a field in my Sybase db, described as date, set to `NULL`. When I read this field on Linux using `SELECT myDate FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE keyField = myKeyValue` I get an invalid date (year 8), but when using `SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE keyField = myKeyValue` and looking at the corresponding field, I get a different invalid date (year 424).

On Windows, in both cases, I get `None`, as expected.

If I manually set the field to a valid date, both Linux and Windows fetch it correctly. Resetting it back to `NULL` has both Windows and Linux revert to the above-described behavior.

I tried upgrading to latest pyodbc, but then I get memory errors running even simple queries. What could possibly be the problem?

Thank you very much.

**UPDATE**

It appears that Linux pyodbc returns invalid dates (with random bogus year values) every time I have the date as `NULL` in the database. Windows version works just fine. This cannot be a pyodbc problem, can it?

Comment: Are you using the same ODBC driver (e.g., FreeTDS ODBC) on both Windows and Linux?

Comment: @GordThompson I think so, but not 100% sure -- how do I test this?

Comment: An ODBC connection must specify the `DRIVER=` to be used, either in the connection string itself or as part of the definition of the DSN (Data Source Name) that is referenced in the connection string.

Comment: @GordThompson My code uses `driver='{Adaptive Server Enterprise}'` on both Windows and Linux